# How to pass ID of selected row in custom list view web part in label of share point 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, list-view, visual-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have created a `XsltListViewWebPart` using `server side object`. Now I have to pass the ID of the selected item into a label. I want to pass the ID without JavaScript.
This is my code for provider

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
using WebPart = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart;
using System.Text;

namespace ConnectedWebPart.WPProvider
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class WPProvider : WebPart, IUser
    {
        string pass;
        // Uncomment the following SecurityPermission attribute only when doing Performance Profiling on a farm solution
        // using the Instrumentation method, and then remove the SecurityPermission attribute when the code is ready
        // for production. Because the SecurityPermission attribute bypasses the security check for callers of
        // your constructor, it's not recommended for production purposes.
        // [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, UnmanagedCode = true)]
        SPSite site;
        public WPProvider()
        {
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {

        }
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get
            { return pass; }
        }
        [ConnectionProvider("UserName")]
        public IUser ConnectionProviderMethod()
        {
            return this;
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            try
            {
                XsltListViewWebPart XLV = new XsltListViewWebPart();
        //        //site = SPContext.Current.Site;
        //        //SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
        //        //SPList splistProduct = web.Lists["Submission Library"];
        //        //SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        //        //query.ViewFields = " <ViewFields>" +
        //        //                                  "<FieldRef Name='ID' />"
        //        //                                  + "<FieldRef Name='DocIcon' />" +
        //        //                                  " <FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' />" +
        //        //                                  "<FieldRef Name='Modified' />" +
        //        //                                  "<FieldRef Name='Editor' />" +
        //        //                     "</ViewFields> ";
        //        //query.RowLimit = 20;
        //        //SPListItemCollection collection = splistProduct.GetItems(query);

        //        //if (collection.Count > 0)
        //        //{
        //        //    GridView1.DataSource = collection.GetDataTable();
        //        //    GridView1.DataBind();
        //        //}


                SPWeb web1 = SPContext.Current.Web;

                SPList lists = web1.Lists["Submission Library"];  //your list name

                XLV.ListId = lists.ID;

                XLV.ViewGuid = lists.DefaultView.ID.ToString(); //default view

                this.Controls.Add(XLV);

                //string selecteditem = lists.gets
                //lbllabel.Text = selecteditem;

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
        }




        //public void GridView1_SelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{
        //    txttext.Text = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
        //    //Label lbllabel = new Label();
        //    //GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        //    pass = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        //    //lbllabel.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
        //    lbllabel.Text = pass;

        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you provide code that you are developing..